# Sybase SQL Anywhere - La conexión/sesión a la base de datos de sybase se corta

Tags: powerbuilder, sybase

Tengo el siguiente problema. Tengo una aplicación hecha con powerbuilder y sybase. Cuando no ejecuto un proceso por un largo tiempo (de mas de dos horas) sobre la base de datos, a las dos horas se corta la conexión.
No me da ningún mensaje de error. simplemente se cierra la sesión/conexión.
Alguna idea o consejo de como solucionar este problema?
Muchas gracias!!!
LA VERSION DE SYBASE ES LA 9 Y LA DE POWER ES LA 12.
adicionel a esto tambien tengo desarrollada una aplicación en IONIC conectado a esa base mediante PHP, dichos servidores estan levantados mediante un ODBC. la conexion tambien se cierra en ese aplicativo, alguna solución a esto?

Answer (score 1):

Tengo entendido que el corte de la conexión tras un tiempo de inactividad se establece por el parámetro IdleTimeout del perfil ODBC, en caso de que no exista uno detallado, toma por default el de la base de datos.

Te recomiendo que pruebes asignarle un valor a dicho parámetro en tu perfil ODBC creado.

Podes ingresear a [este link](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00170.1540/doc/html/san1283555399516.html) para que sirva de base ante alguna duda;

Saludos.-

Comment: muchas gracias, si estas en lo correcto, se hace agregando el parametro IDLE en la conexion quedando de la siguiente manera:
SQLCA.DBMS = "TRACE ODBC"
SQLCA.AutoCommit = False
SQLCA.DBParm = "ConnectString='DSN=ASA 9.0 ClientSample;UID=dba;PWD=sql;LivenessTimeout=70;Idle=60',CursorScroll='Static',CursorLock='Lock',ConnectOption='SQL_DRIVER_CONNECT,SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT',StaticBind=0"
donde idle es el tiempo de desconexion y liveness el tiempo de espera que tendrá cada petición, gracias por la respuesta